# Option on homepage to show only questions with favorite tags or all questions and ui to add tags to favorite or ignore from hover menu

Tags: feature-request, user-interface

I think it would be good to have an option on home screen to switch from all questions to those with favorite tags.
I know about https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=intags%3amine%20is%3aquestion but I think it should be more straightforward for everyone, especially new users.
Something like that(top left corner)
[image]

And I think it would be good to have an option when hovering on tags to add them to favorites or to ignore.
Like that [image]